# Add a hook to run when NetworkManager connects

Tags: networkmanager, dbus

What would be a good way to make a script run every time my computer connects to the network in Ubuntu?  Would I somehow use dbus to do this?

Background: when I'm on the train I run a short Perl script to click a button on the splash page.  That way I can immediately use the internet without having to manually visit a pointless website. My script is a near-perfect solution, but it would be perfect if it could run automatically any time I connect to the network.

Comment: not important to the question, but here is the one-liner: alias dodgesplash='perl -e '\''use WWW::Mechanize; $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(); $mech->get("http://is.gd"); $mech->click();'\'''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` and make it executable.

Answer (score 6):

You can put a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` which will be run whenever a connection goes up or down. See the man page for `NetworkManager` for the details.